# #error "Need to define M2M_POINTER_SIZE_IN_BYTES"

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, atmelstudio

I'm trying to compile the WINC1500 driver in atmel studio and I'm running into this error saying

"error "Need to define M2M_POINTER_SIZE_IN_BYTES"

I'm using the AT32UC3C1256C MCU and have it defined in the winc1500_driver_config.h file. I don't know how to solve this error, I've been following the instructions below to try getting the WINC1500 module to interface with the MCU.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Adding-an-ATWINC15x0-Wi-Fi-Network-Controller-to-a-Microcontroller-Application-Application-Note-DS00002907B.pdf

```
// Set the size of host MCU pointer, in bytes.  Pointer sizes vary depending on the MCU 
// architecture.  The pointer size can be determined by executing the code: 
 //   int x = sizeof(int *);  
#if defined(__PIC32MX__) || defined(__PIC32MZ__)
    #define M2M_POINTER_SIZE_IN_BYTES     4
#elif defined(__C30__)
    #define M2M_POINTER_SIZE_IN_BYTES     2 //2
#elif defined(__XC8)
    #define M2M_POINTER_SIZE_IN_BYTES     3 
#elif defined(__SAMD21J18A__)
    #define M2M_POINTER_SIZE_IN_BYTES     4
#elif defined(__AT32UC3C1256C__)
    #define M2M_POINTER_SIZE_IN_BYTES     4    // 32 bit microcontroller, the pointer size is 4 bytes
#else    
    #error "Need to define M2M_POINTER_SIZE_IN_BYTES"
#endif
```

Comment: You need to define macro __AT32UC3C1256C__ in project settings

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny Sounds more like he should set correct target cpu in project settings.